#  why a # character is added to the url?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, actionlink

I have a simple page displaying thumbnail list ,

I want to to add a pager  , i have added two action links

```
  <li class="ui-pagination-next">@Html.ActionLink("Next", "Paginate", "Home", new { nbSkip = ViewBag.nextSkip }, null)</li>
```

when i click on the link i'm redirected to

```
http://localhost:41626/#/Home/Paginate?nbSkip=60
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:41626/Home/Paginate?nbSkip=60 ,
```

does anyone know why the '#' character is added to the URL ?

Route copnfig :

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at your `li` class of `ui-pagination-next` [im assuming](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ui-pagination-next) jQuery Mobile is being used here.

jQuery Mobile by default, [makes your links AJAX enabled](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-links.html)

---

If you wish, you can prevent this by using:

```
$.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
       $.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false; 
   });
</script>
```

Comment: the question was not how to solve this but what is hash and why is it used

Comment: @ParvSharma Reformatted my answer. My answer provides documentation links as to why this is in place, and the option to disable

Answer (score 4):

by looking at your code i could find `ui-pagination-next`
this might mean that some other JS framework is actually listening to the click events of this link and doing some kind of ajax
hash `"#"` character is being used so that actually browser does not redirects to the page and at the same time maintains history
so if you press the browsers back button this additional peice of the link after `#` is removed and any JS framework subscribed to the evet knows how to handle it then

**in simpler terms.** 
anything after the `#` in a `url` isnt sent to the server. Because some JS framework is handling the ajax part, it does not want that request should directly go to the server and also at the same time show look proper in the browsers address bar hence adds whatever you have in the link after the # and carries on with AJAX
[heres](https://developers.google.com/tv/web/articles/location-hash-navigation) an indepth article using hash for back and forward

Answer (score 0):

If i were you , I would use Ajax Raw ActionLink :

```
@Ajax.RawActionLink("NameofLink", "Action", "Controller", new { oid = 0, type = "oid and type are 2 parameters you want to send to action " }, new { id = "btnNewB", @class = "anyclass" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your responses,

well seen @curt, in fact I'm using jQuery mobile, and what was causing the problem is `mobile.changePage`

Now I'm using simple button to navigate throw pages, but

```
$.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;
```

Does not resolve my problem with ajax link's. So I've done this, and it's working now

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Previous", "Index", new { nbSkip = ViewBag.previousSkip }, new { data_role = "button", data_icon = "arrow-l", rel = "external", data_ajax = false })
```

Thanks @Parv Sharma for your explanation